# How do I set up DNS for two servers within one domain using gandi.net DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have two servers, server A, and server B. I also have a domain name, example.com.

I want server A to be reachable by example.com, and I want server B to be reachable by server-b.example.com.

I'm using gandi.net for DNS management.

How do I set this up?

Comment: Set up a DNS record for each one. What's confusing?

Comment: Honestly, it took me less time to find the documentation than it will have taken you to write your question. [Google](http://google.com) has this new fangled search engine thingummy- learn to use it and read documentation - it's the way forward.

Comment: Thanks for the condescending responses, I reeeaaally appreciate it.

Comment: I had already searched for this information. I wouldn't have asked otherwise. The snag I ran into appeared to be the TTL was set too low, but the gandi.net interface never told me this, so I wanted to ask this question more generally in case I was missing something not so obvious. Geez.

Comment: @brlafreniere I'm sorry if you feel that the responses you've received are "condescending", but Server Fault is a site for [professionals](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5475/why-professional-capacity). The kind of question you're asking is beyond basic - if you don't have this level of knowledge you're not ready to be managing DNS. If you're struggling with the basics of DNS I ***STRONGLY*** suggest you pick up and read [DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) - doing your own research is the proper, professional thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manage your zone file.

Ghandi.net provides a nice web interface from which you can edit the zone file and add suitable (A) records to your zone.

[Ghandi seems to provide documentation on how to do this too.](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/dns/zone)

Comment: Thanks, the documentation you linked appears to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows Server (or even a linux server for that matter)....

Install DNS (named, bind, etc) on server a, then create a record for server b and use it's public IP address.

If you want them both to be accessable from example.com, and they are both webservers. point the name servers to each server (create a record ns1.example.com with ip A and ns2.example.com with IP B)

Hope this helps.